# What test can I run to ensure my Express server, session values are being stored in Redis?

Tags: node.js, cookies, redis

**Question:**  How can I confirm that the session values from my simple node.js test app are being stored in Redis?

**Backstory:**  I am hosting this app on a Digital Ocean server running Centos.  Redis is installed on the server and I confirmed that it was turned on using the ping command.  With the app running I checked the / endpoint in Chrome and the route fired as expected.  Everything seems fine but how do I check to see if Redis is actually storing the session values?

```
$ redis-cli ping // PONG
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const app = express();
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

const PORT = 8080;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
    name: 'randomWord',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'superSecretKey',
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        secure: false,
    } 
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.counter += 1;
    res.render('index', { output: req.session.counter });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log( `app listening on port ${PORT}` ));
```

**from index.ejs**

```
<h1><%= output %></h1>
```

Comment: Assuming the redis server is outside the node.js process, you can have a cilent create a session, puts some state in the session, then stop and restart your Express server,   If the session data is still there for that client, then it's persistent beyond the Express process so it has to be stored somewhere else (which would be redis in this case).  If the session data is not still there, then it apparently was only in the Express process in memory.

Comment: Are you not able to view the Redis data by connecting to the Redis instance? I use [Keylord](https://protonail.com/) to connect to remote servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to verify it, but probably the simpler is to connect to your Redis instance and have a look at the commands going through. An example:

```
$ redis-cli
$ monitor
```

With the monitor command, Redis will print every single command reaching the server. With your Express server up and running, try logging in, or whatever action triggers a session creation in your system. Watch the logs printed by the monitor command, and you'll easily be able to tell whether the sessions are being stored in Redis.

For further validation, stop the Express instance and run it again; you should still have the session available, as it's not stored in memory, but instead using Redis.